# In django, is there a way to keep a user on a stage of a wizard until they're reado to move on?

Tags: python, django, user-interface, django-formwizard

In django, is there a way to keep users on a stage of a forms wizard until they're ready?

[image: Something like this.]

Where if a user clicks on yes, the current contents of that stage are saved, the stage cleared and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to control form validation, submission, workflow, etc. I'm not entirely sure what you want, but if you need more precise control over the client-side interaction you'll almost certainly need to use javascript.